# elbow method valueError

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means

x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)

This is the code, I don't know why python don't show me the plot in correct form. Cna you show me why?

```
distortions= []
for i in range (1, 11):
  Km = KMeans(n_clusters = i, 
              init= 'k-means++',
              n_init=10,
              max_iter= 300, 
              random_state=0)
  Km.fit(X)
  distortions.append(Km.inertia_)

  plt.plot(range(1, 11), distortions, marker ='o')
  plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
  plt.ylabel('Distortion') 
  plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)` is due to a wrong identation of the code that prints the plot. Change it to be outside the loop.

**Corrected version:**

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


X = np.random.rand(100, 10)

distortions = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    Km = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init="k-means++", n_init=10, max_iter=300, random_state=0)
    Km.fit(X)
    distortions.append(Km.inertia_)


plt.plot(range(1, 11), distortions, marker="o")
plt.xlabel("Number of clusters")
plt.ylabel("Distortion")
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image: plot]